# Подскажите с ошибкой при сборке sass

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass

Windows 8 x64, python 2.7, npm 2.10.1
Не подгружаются стили при сборке
В консоли ошибки sass иероглифами, плюс пишет мол пути не инжектятся, хотя у человека который передал проект всё собирается у него Mac.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Была такая проблема, только с grunt, попробуй написать имя пользователя на английском. Как это сделать здесь - http://answers.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/forum/windows8_1-files/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA/5a37c907-9fc5-4b01-ab3c-4268cd75b5a5

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).